# Android button onClick is not getting triggered

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, android-button

All other things are working perfectly. only Button is not working.
I also checked the id in declaration. it's same as in `XML` file.
I add a Toast in `onClick()` for checking. 
But toast is not displayed in output.
so `onClick()` in not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are not seeing a `Toast` is because you never call `show()` on it. It has to look like this

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Btn Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And besides that in Java you do not compare Strings with `==` but with the `equals()` method.

Comment: Yeah .. Bro . String comparison is the actual problem, that's why background task is not working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `show()` on Toast. i.e.

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Btn Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to show the Toast.

Comment: Ohhh shit ... I just forgot it .... I think I have a problem in Async task .... I will find it ..... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Btn Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

To:

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Btn Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```